# "object doesn't support property or method" inside generic autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

When setting up an autocomplete the following line works fine:

```
$("[id$='_txtUserName']").autocomplete({  ... etc
```

But I want to refactor a bit and create a generic function into which I can pass any text box as an object and there is more than one textbox I need to set up similarly. Unfortunately the following code does not work

```
function SetupAutocomplete(ctrl) {
    ctrl.autocomplete({  ... etc
```

... as when calling it in either of these ways:

```
SetupAutocomplete($("[id$='_txtUserName']").get(0));
```

or

```
SetupAutocomplete($("[id$='_txtUserName']")[0])
```

..neither work and it throws the `object does not support the property or method 'autocompete'` error. I really don't want to have to write the same thing *x* number of times for each text box I need to setup.

Any ideas on why it doesn't like the `ctrl.autocomplete` line? I'm guessing because it doesn't know it's a text input type but why not and what can I do about it?

Server side is c# but doubt that's at all relevant as it works fine when setting up the autocomplete explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Uh ok so this is embarrassing, I should have been calling the function like so:

```
SetupAutocomplete($("[id$='_txtUserName']"));
```